# On click of a button makes an apex callout

Tags: apex, integration, custom-button, callout

I would like to display a custom button on a page layout. I would like to add my apex callout logic to the custom button.

When looking at what functionality that can be added to the custom button , I am able to see only the option to have a VF page / on click Java script code. How can I incorporate an apex callout code to the custom button?

Comment: One of the options may be using a web service, and calling them via JS

Comment: You can do the callout from your `Visualforce` controller/extension...

Comment: Not 100% sure I agree on the dupe vote here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is using a controller extension:

```
public with sharing class MyCalloutExtension
{
    final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public MyCalloutExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    public PageReference makeCallout()
    {
        // make callout here
        // optionally add try/catch and surface errors in UI
        return controller.view();
    }
}
```

Then your minimal markup would look something like:

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c"
           extensions="MyCalloutExtension"
           action="{!makeCallout}">
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe the controller.view() brings me back to the same page where I was before?

Comment: @SfdcBat If you click it from the detail page, yes.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if I should ask this here but I am trying to display the error message on the page the place where you have - // optionally add try/catch and surface errors in UI. I am using ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'test message on page')); , but the error is not displayed. Maybe it is due to  return controller.view(); ? How can solve this?

Comment: Is the above requirement even possible. I do not want to write a VF page just to show the error, if I can show the error on standard detail page that would be great